# External swf is playing when preloader does not complete

Tags: actionscript-3, external, preloader, swfloader

External swf is playing when preloader does not complete.I can not access external swf.My codes(AS 3.0)

```
package com
{
    public class MainClass extends Sprite
    {
        private static var file:String = "Movie.swf";
        private var loader:Loader;

        static var txt:TextField = new TextField  ;
        static var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat  ;
        format.color = "0X003333";
        format.font = "Arial";
        format.size = "38";
        txt.defaultTextFormat = format;

        public function MainClass()
        {
            loader = new Loader  ;
            loader.load(new URLRequest(file));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,preLoad);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showContent);
        }

        private function preLoad(e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            var perc = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal;
            txt.text = Math.ceil(perc * 100).toString();
            txt.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            txt.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            mc.addChild(txt);
        }

        private function showContent(e:Event):void
        {
            mc.removeChild(txt);
            mc.addChild(loader);
            mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 1 - mc.width / 1;
            mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 1.5 - mc.height / 1.5;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your loaded MC is a timeline animation, you should put a Stop(); to the first frame. Then start it when you are really done loading.